# CSS repeating gradient with offset

Tags: css

I am trying to add some CSS styling to my website and I'm having a bit of difficulty that I would like your help with.

I am trying to achieve the following result:

https://jsfiddle.net/mb3yzc49/1/

```
<style>
  .gradient {
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(#E8EDEF, #e8edee 50px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 115px);
  }

  .list-item img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
  }

  .gradient li {
    list-style: none;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }

  .list-item {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 50px;
  }

</style>
<div class="gradient" style="width:100%;">
  Title
  <ul style="width:100px;">
    <li class="list-item">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" />
      text
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" />
      text

    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" />
      text

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But my problem is that this section has a title, and the HTML is external, so final result is something of the following:

https://jsfiddle.net/mb3yzc49/

You notice the problem with title, that is taking some of the background and causing misalignment for following items. Is there any solution for this without modifying the HTML (is external)?

Thanks.

Edit: Sorry about formatting, this editor isn't so friendly.

Comment: apply the gradient to `ul`?

Comment: @TemaniAfif first of all thank you for the fast reply. There is an edit I made maybe too late, the <ul> tag has a fixed width and I would like the background to stretch on the entire page.

Comment: and the gradient div to only the ul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap the title within a span:

```
<span>Title</span>
```

and give the span an absolute positioning:

```
.gradient > span {
  position: absolute;
}
```